# Proper method of safely shipping an SSD?

Tags: ssd

I ordered an SSD. It arrived in its box inside another cardboard box, but the online retailer didn't ship it with bubble-wrap or anything else besides the cardboard to absorb impacts.

Given that the SSD has (I assume) no moving parts and it works - should I be asking for a refund anyway? I'm concerned the integrity of the product has been degraded by potentially rough shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSD's have no moving parts so no damage of the drive will occur when bubble wrap isn't used.

Comment: I once had a pair of SSDs in clamshell packs, put in an envelope and just thrown into my apartment. They are fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Anti-ESD bags or wraping are essential. My experience with ssd's is that they are very sensitive to static, especially the m.2 types.
2. Use bubble wrap, if you need to send a ssd back to it's manufacturer, you don't want them to void the warranty based off of improperly shipping it, you should take every precaution.
3. It's worth it to pay the extra couple bucks for insurance shipping it, if something happens in transit, the manufacturer **will not be held responsible**.

Also note: it's good practice to use ESD wrist bands (properly grounded) or use a anti-ESD work pad. I've also seen other computer repair technicians use the "touch bare metal case" method to discharge themselves. I wouldn't personally recommend that method because the computer needs to be plugged in and proper grounding at the outlet for that to work. (Also it's a step you can easily forget to do...)

I realize this is an old post, and put this answer up for future readers.